# when does webview success to load js?(it seems webview does not have the callback)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

**I want to invoke js function after loadurl(), but i do not know when the url(http) is loaded sussefully. And webview does not have the believable callback functions**

When the webview load html page, I do not know when the js could success be loaded. And there is not callback function to be override.

It seems that  **onPageFinished()** function is not believable, and

webview.loadUrl("javascript:**window.onload**=funtion(){callback()}")

also have some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you did like this

```
        webView.loadUrl(link);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
```

Comment: do you means the code before could solve this problem?I did not try it like you said before.